# Edges not translating correctly from data.frame to geom_net correlation plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot pearson correlation networks using the geom_net package in R and am failing thus far. I do not 'need' to use geom_net, but had chosen geom_net because being able to work from a dataframe originally seemed intuitive compared to the edge/vertex syntax with GGally. I do however want to use a ggplot based option as compared to base package alternatives because the end goal is to merge my ggplot network with other ggplot figures using the gridExtra package. The color is relevant for showing positive and negative correlations, and is consistently showing up as the wrong color for just a few edges. Additionally, one node is showing up as unconnected and I have no idea why.

I have been troubleshooting with helpful suggestions from here ([Geomnet package - error with user-defined coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962450/geomnet-package-error-with-user-defined-coordinates)) and here ([Inproper show when use geom_net in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976716/inproper-show-when-use-geom-net-in-r)). The first link having a comment about labels being lost/mismatched and essentially fixing that issue by having your from and to vectors set as characters. This was an issue that I thought I had fixed by switching to letter characters, but does not appear to be the case (atleast in every instance, though it does seem to have helped). The second being for nodes not appearing because a vertex only appears as a 'to' character and not a 'from' character. Adding a 'from' for the missing vertex with an NA 'to' helped with that problem.

```
library(geomnet)

from = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "b", "d", "l", "b", "d", "j", "n", "b", "d", "g", "k", "n", "o", "n", "p", "m", "q", "r")
to = c("b", "c", "l", "l", "l", "m", "m", "m", "o", "o", "o", "o", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "q", "r", NA, NA, NA )
col = c("darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "red", "red", "red","red",      
    "red","red","darkgreen", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red",  NA,NA, NA )
dat = data.frame(from, to, col)
dat$from = as.character(dat$from)
dat$to = as.character(dat$to)

ggplot(data = dat, aes(from_id = from,to_id = to)) + theme_net() + 
geom_net(directed = FALSE, labelon = TRUE, repel = FALSE, ecolour = 
dat$col, labelcolour = "white", size = 12, layout.alg = 
"fruchtermanreingold")

dat
```

The first and most obvious problem is that the 'r' node is unconnected by edges, but it should be connected to 'p' by a red edge.

When you view dat, an example node that shows that my code is wrong was that 'o' is showing 4 red edges and 1 green in the plot, while all rows involving an 'o' should be red according to dat.

I am going to keep messing with this and will update if I figure it out, but would appreciate any input on fixing these issues with my plot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I seem to have figured out my problem, and had a chance to test my solution in a larger dataset. Decided to post in case anyone else has a similar issue. In any case I highly recommend you find a way to check that your nodes are connected as you would expect when using geomnet. [image]

Apparently ordering `dat` by `from` sets the order and geomnet doesn't have to reorganize my dataframe, thereby dissociating values from their proper columns. Additionally using a letter or number character does not matter, as long as it is in fact a character.

So my original code only needs to modified to include this line before plotting:

```
dat = dat[order(dat$from),]
```